# Как в базе aspnet_Users сбросить пароль?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Как в базе где есть таблицы aspnet_Users , aspnet_Application сбросить пароль? Или как получить значение пароля? В процедуре сброса `aspnet_Membership_ResetPassword` есть параметры пароль (не знаю шифрованый или нет), соль, поэтому не очевидно как её задействовать. Если есть доступ к этой базе - как оживить авторизацию? 
И последнее, как эта система называется (если можно)? 
Из имен вижу слова SqlMembershipProvider и SqlProfileProvider.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нашёл  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305815/how-to-manually-change-password-in-asp-net-membership нечто, получил два base64 значения которые никак не похожи на пароль.

Comment: Я уже вписал в aspnet_Membership_GetPassword "заглушку" на пароли (взяв юзверя по ссылке выше) - всёравно не помогло. Может ещё нужно что-то в web.config проверить?